# Hide Profile Field if User Meta is blank - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Good evening everybody!

I'd like to hide a profile field if the user meta is blank.

For example, in the image, I'd like to hide the `billing_ateco` row because `billing_ateco` field is empty.

[image]

I have no idea where to start, if you have the solution or suggest me one similar thread (I didn't find anything in the similar questions section when I posted this) It would be a great help, thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a javascript question, I updated the tag. (PHP does not know what the user types in the browser until the request is sent, so you have to use JS)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'user meta'?

Comment: The question has already been answered at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/238283.

Answer (score 0):

If by `user meta` you mean user input, one approach would be to find all input elements, check  if their value is empty and then hide their parent `tr` element.

```js
// Find all <input> elements:
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach( input =>{
  // Check to see if the value is empty:
  if ( input.value.trim() === "" ){
    // Find the closest <tr> parent of the input and 
    // hide it:
    input.closest("tr").style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="a">Label A</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="a" />
    </td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="b">Label B</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="b" />
    </td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="c">Label C</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="c" value="Value" />
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```